# How to enable a network card using PowerShell in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

I get a term not recognized error when I run the following 3 lines of code, but if I enter the netsh command directly in PowerShell it works.  What's wrong with my approach?

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("netsh interface set interface \"Wi-Fi\" admin=enable");
ps.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Invoke-Expression, as netsh is not a valid Powershell command

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.AddCommand("Invoke-Expression");
ps.AddArgument("netsh interface set interface \"Wi-Fi\" admin=enable");
// if you need the result save it in a psobject
Collection<PSObject> result =  ps.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```